# Index string for optimize search in Microsoft Access SQL

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a Microsoft Access file (.mdb) with 2.000.000 row on it and i'm using a query :

```
select count(*) from tblABC where instr(Column1 , "something") > 0
```

to get all record contain the word 'something' on it. However the query freeze for 40 second before return result and it's terrible for me because i need to do it usually. How do i optimize the search by give it an index like other number column ?

Comment: Well, that query will need a full table scan at all times. You could try to use `where column1 like '*something*'` which might be slightly quicker because it doesn't involve the VBA engine.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the comment above, `LIKE "*...*"` does seem to be significantly faster than `InStr(...) > 0`. When I tested it on a table with a million rows the code

```
Sub SearchTest()
Dim t0 As Single, strWhere As String
t0 = Timer
strWhere = "InStr(TextField, ""86753"") > 0"
Debug.Print DCount("*", "MillionRows", strWhere) & " row(s) found"
Debug.Print "Search took " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.0") & " seconds"
End Sub
```

reported

```
20 row(s) found
Search took 5.4 seconds
```

and when I changed the search string to

```
strWhere = "TextField LIKE ""*86753*"""
```

it reported

```
20 row(s) found
Search took 3.4 seconds
```

I also tested it with and without an index on [TextField] and the index made no difference to the results in my case. However, [TextField] was also unique ("Item0000001", "Item0000002", ... "Item1000000"), so an index on that field *might* have made a difference if the field had contained different data (although I wouldn't bet on it).